# Access to Docker RabbitMQ Cluster Fails on Masstransit

Tags: docker, rabbitmq, masstransit

I have hosted two Docker containers with RabbitMQ (see the Docker file below). I combined two RabbitMQ instances to a cluster using `rabbitmqctl join_cluster`. The cluster name of both RabbitMQ instances is `rabbit@rabbit`.

If I use `rabbitmq://localhost:5673/` as a connection url, I am able to communicate with single instance of the cluster. However, if I use `rabbitmq://rabbit@rabbit/`, MassTransit fails to connect.

How can I compose a connection string for MassTransit, which can communicate with RabbitMQ cluster (with fail-over management)?

```
public static IBusControl ConfigureBus(string rabbitMqUri, string userName, string password)
{
    return Bus.Factory.CreateUsingRabbitMq(cfg =>
    {
        var host = cfg.Host(new Uri(rabbitMqUri), hst =>
        {
            hst.Username(userName);
            hst.Password(password);
         });
    });
}
```

**Docker file**

```
    version: '2'
    services:
    rabbit:
        image: rabbitmq:management
        hostname: rabbit
        ports:
            - "5673:5672"
            - "15678:15672"
        environment:
            - RABBITMQ_ERLANG_COOKIE='mysecret'
    hamster:
        image: rabbitmq:management
        hostname: hamster
        ports:
            - "5674:5672"
            - "15679:15672"
        environment:
            - RABBITMQ_ERLANG_COOKIE='mysecret'
```

Answer (score 0):

Cluster name says nothing about the physical connection parameters. `rabbitmq://rabbit@rabbit/` makes sense only in an existing RabbitMQ context but by no way it explains the client where to find your nodes.

In MassTransit, you need to specify additional host configuration to use RabbitMQ cluster:

```
public static IBusControl ConfigureBus(string[] clusterNodes, 
                                       string userName, string password) =>
    Bus.Factory.CreateUsingRabbitMq(cfg =>
    {
        var host = cfg.Host(new Uri(rabbitMqUri), h =>
        {
            h.Username(userName);
            h.Password(password);
            h.UseCluster(cluster =>
            {
                foreach (var node in clusterNodes)
                    cluster.Node(node);
            });
         });
    });
```

where `clusterNodes` is the list of host names or IP addresses (without `rabbitmq://` prefix) of the physical nodes in your cluster.

Comment: Should rabbitMqUri be equal to clusterNodes[0] ?